# Load UIView from XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib

I'm looking for some advice on how to load UIView from XIB file. I tried following 5th solution from this [tutorial](http://eppz.eu/blog/uiview-from-xib/).

However, the button actions won’t work. I setup my project almost exactly as the tutorial, but the IBAction just won’t get called at all. I'm not sure if adaptive layout caused this weirdness or not.

Would you be kind enough to take a quick look at what happened in my project? I created a small project just to get the button working and is [placed here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66024121/View_XIB.zip)

Here is the code snippet:

```
@interface ProfileHeadingViewOwner : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet ProfileHeadingView *profileHeadingView;
@end

@implementation ProfileHeadingViewOwner
@end

static ProfileHeadingViewOwner* __owner = nil;

@interface ProfileHeadingView ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *profileName;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController <ProfileHeadingViewDelegate> *delegateViewController;
@end

@implementation ProfileHeadingView

+(void)presentInViewController:(UIViewController<ProfileHeadingViewDelegate>*) viewController
{
    // Instantiating encapsulated here.
    //ProfileHeadingViewOwner *owner = [ProfileHeadingViewOwner new];
    __owner = [ProfileHeadingViewOwner new];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self) owner:__owner options:nil];

    // Pass in a reference of the viewController.
    __owner.profileHeadingView.delegateViewController = viewController;


    // Add (thus retain).
    [viewController.view addSubview:__owner.profileHeadingView];
}

+(void)setProfileName:(NSString*)name {
    __owner.profileHeadingView.profileName.text = name;
}


-(IBAction)editAvatarButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    ////// THIS METHOD WON'T GET CALLED. WHY? ///////

    [self.delegateViewController uploadProfileAvatar:self];
}
```

The `editAvatarButtonPressed`: method won't get called when the button is clicked.

Thanks in advance.
Loc Pham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues in your code.

1. You are not assigning any value to `__owner.profileHeadingView`
2. Your xib is not correct, you have a top `UIView`. You need to remove that.

For fixing first issue, you need to do like:

```
__owner = [ProfileHeadingViewOwner new];
__owner.profileHeadingView = (ProfileHeadingView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self) owner:__owner options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
__owner.profileHeadingView.delegateViewController = viewController;
```

For fixing second issue, change your xib design from:

[image: Current]

to:

[image: Correct]

Comment: Thanks Midhun MP. This solved my problem and I've marked this as the right answer. Just out of curiosity, if you observe the sample project from the author giving the said tutorial, he did exactly what I did, but somehow, it works.  Here's his sample project on Github and "Decoupled" is his way of implementing XIB that makes the XIB view standalone and reusable. https://github.com/eppz/iOS.Blog.UIView_from_Xib

Comment: @LocPham: You are welcome. I'm checking his project.